# Filling a given dimension inteligently while reshaping array in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have `n` observations of some field over a `100x100` grid, and that this data is stored as a single vector `obs`. I would like to reshape this into a `100x100xn` array without knowing what `n` is advance. In matlab I can use

```
reshape(obs,100,100,[]);
```

or in python

```
np.reshape(obs,(100,100,-1))
```

Is there similar functionality in R or do I have to manually calculate the size of the last index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (I am sure you can adapt it to your further needs):

```
shaper <- function(obs, a, b) {
 array(obs, dim=c(a, b, length(obs)/a/b))
}
shaper(obs, 100, 100)
```

If you are not sure whether the size will be correct that you require, you can include a check to see if there are leftovers, something like this:

```
shaper <- function(obs, a, b) {
  dimension <- length(obs)/a/b 
  if (dimension %% 1 != 0) { 
   stop("not correctly divisible")
  }
  else {
   return(array(obs, dim=c(a, b, dimension)))
  }
}
shaper(obs, 100, 100)
```

Also added the functionality to give any amount of dimensions as input, and it will try to extend it by 1.

```
shaper <- function(obs, ...) {
 len.remaining <- length(obs)
 for (i in c(...)) {
   len.remaining <- len.remaining / i
 }
 if (len.remaining %% 1 != 0) { 
  stop("not correctly divisible")
 }
 else {
  return(array(obs, dim=c(..., len.remaining)))
 } 
}
```

Now it will be possible to use:

```
obs <- rep(1, 100 * 100 * 5)
> res <- shaper(obs, 100, 100)
> dim(res) 
[1] 100 100 5
> res <- shaper(obs, 10, 10, 100)
> dim(res)
[1] 10 10 100 5
```

Comment: thanks, i guess i was looking for a standard function to do this. i guess it would be relatively easy to implement np.reshape in r though

Comment: cool. i like the "..." and the error handling. pretty convenient.

Answer (score 2):

Does this what do you want?

```
 dim(obs) <- c(100,100,length(v)/100/100)
```

For example:

```
v <- seq(2*2*3)
dim(v) <- c(2,2,length(v)/2/2)

, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8

, , 3

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    9   11
[2,]   10   12
```

Note that for

```
  v <- seq(2*2*3+1)
```

You will get an error :

```
Error in dim(v) <- c(2, 2, length(v)/2/2) : 
  dims [product 12] do not match the length of object [13]
```

Comment: I don't think this is what OP is looking for. The 3rd dimension should be the length of `obs`.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde  Maybe , how do you understand this sentence: " n observations of some field over a 100x100 grid" ?

Comment: I think that's incidental information, but the question isn't entirely clear. FWIW his python example breaks for me.

Answer (score 0):

Working off of dualinity's code above I implemented an R function like the np.reshape syntax

```
npreshape <- function(x,shape) {
    x<- array(x)
    ind <- which(shape ==  -1)
    shape[ind] = prod(dim(x))/prod(shape[-ind])
    return(array(x,shape))
}
```

Here is how it works in console

```
> npreshape(1:10,c(-1,5))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    9
[2,]    2    4    6    8   10
```